# How to add image to JButton?

Tags: java, jbutton

Please help. I searched everywhere but I can't add image to JButton.

I tried setIcon() but this didn't work.
I'm making Game and my path to image is /textures/StartButton.png

There is my code:

```
package com.GermanySimulator.states;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import com.GermanySimulator.display.Window;
import com.GermanySimulator.graphics.AssetsLoader;

public class MainMenuState extends State {

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private MouseEvent e;
private int StartButtonWidth = 100;
private int StartButtonHeight = 50;
private int StartButtonX = Window.width / 2 - StartButtonWidth;
private int StartButtonY = Window.height / 4;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private State gamestate = new GameState();
static Icon StartIcon = new ImageIcon("/textures/StartButton.png");
public static JButton StartButton = new JButton(StartIcon);
public static boolean clicktimer = true;

@Override
public void tick() {
}

@Override
public void render(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(AssetsLoader.mainmenu, 0, 0, null);
    StartButton.setBounds(StartButtonX, StartButtonY, StartButtonWidth, StartButtonHeight);
    StartButton.setVisible(true);
    StartButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(clicktimer == true) {
            System.out.println("Click!");
            clicktimer = false;
            }
        }   
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Try `getClass().getResource("textures/StartButton.png")` instead of `/textures/StartButton.png`. Also, where is your `textures/` folder located? It should be under `src` folder I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `javax.imageio.ImageIO` for that and it should work, make sure the path is correct, if you are not sure just give all the path (c:\folder\....\textures\StartButton.png) and try something like that.

```
JButton StartButton = new JButton();
      try {
        Image startImage =ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/textures/StartButton.png"));
        StartButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(startImage));
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [java.awt.Toolkit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getImage-java.lang.String-) for this:

```
Image image = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("/textures/StartButton.png");
JButton button = new JButton(new ImageIcon(image));
```

Note, that `getImage()` caches images. If you want to avoid that, use `createImage()` instead.